# Giving month names to a variable of numbers in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with the variable 'months' from 1 to 12, but need to change them to the month names. i.e "1" needs to be January and so on. Whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `month.name[months]` or if it is a character vector `month.name[as.numeric(months)]` or if it is a factor variable `month.name[as.numeric(as.character(months))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has an inbuilt vector called `month.name` for your purpose you could do something like the following:

```
# Some dummy data
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  month = sample(1:12, size = 10)
)

# Now use your integer month to subset month.name
df$month2 <- month.name[df$month] # Also has month.abb
df

   month    month2
1      9 September
2      4     April
3      7      July
4      1   January
5      2  February
6      5       May
7      3     March
8      8    August
9      6      June
10    11  November
```